# Avoid giving login credentials in web master tools api

Tags: python, gdata-api, google-search-console

I am using Google's webmaster tools API to extract my site performance report. I feel insecure exposing my login credentials in the python file which is used to extract date. I am using gdata-python client from this [SOURCE](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2011/12/download-search-queries-data-using.html). Is there any way to do it securely?